# SVG : Link to a location in the containing document

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm currently developing a site which uses a SVG based map, with clickable points in it. Idealy I would like these maps to point to locations in the HTML document that contains it (one for each region).

HTML :

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://ffu.jmaris.me/carte.svg">
  Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
<div id="region1" class="region"> Stuff ...</div>
<div id="region2" class="region"> Stuff ...</div>
<div id="region3" class="region"> Stuff ...</div>
<div id="region4" class="region"> Stuff ...</div>
```

CSS :

```
.region {display:none;}
.region div:target{display:block;}
```

I'd like to be able to point to page.html#region2 inside my SVG without using absolute paths (as its currently running on a developpment server,and, in addition, after deployment the URL risks changing in the future.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you ok to use js ? Anchors inside an object will change the object's document's location, not the main document.

Comment: i'm OK using JS if it makes it possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to rely on javascript here.

Anchors (`<a>`) inside an `<object>` will change the object's document's location, so we can't use it directly.
However, if your files share the same origin, <sub>and that you are not running the whole thing in an overly protected iframe like the ones of stacksnippets™</sub> you can access the parent document quite easily :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <a id="loc1" xlink:href="#">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="green"/>
    </a>
    <a id="loc2" xlink:href="#">
      <rect x="50" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="red"/>
    </a>
    <script>
    var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    anchors.forEach(function(a){
        a.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            // where anchor's id represent parent doc element's ids.
            window.parent.location.hash = this.id;
            });
        });
    </script>
</svg>
```

[**Live plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/l0H0w3hOW0UgTVhiLLgM?p=preview)

And a workaround which uses the [PostMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for overly protected iframes :

```js
window.onmessage = e => {
  // you may want to be sure this is the message you want
  window.location.hash = e.data;
}
// here it would be saved as an external file
document.querySelector('object').data = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <a id="loc1" xlink:href="#">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="green"/>
  </a>
  <a id="loc2" xlink:href="#">
    <rect x="50" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="red"/>
  </a>
  <script>
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  anchors.forEach(function(a){
    a.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      // post our #id
      window.parent.postMessage( this.id, '*' );
      });
    });
  <\/script>
</svg>
`], {
  type: 'image/svg+xml'
}));
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<object data="file.svg"></object>
<div id="loc1">loc1</div>
<div id="loc2">loc2</div>
```